# How to use HTML/CSS for reusable styled boxes in Bookdown

Tags: html, css, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to create reusable sections for my `bookdown` project.

**What works**: I create a `style.css` including

```
.titeldefbox{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.defbox{
  background-position: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(
  315deg,
  hsl(240deg 50% 95%) 0%,
  hsl(158deg 13% 64%) 100%);
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.svgdefbox{
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.defbox h2{
font-size: 16px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px 0 10px 15px;
}

.defbox p{
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

I call a div span in any .Rmd as

```
::::: {.defbox}
A **definition** is a statement of the meaning of a term.
:::::
```

Renders to:

[image]

---

**What does not work**: A friend of mine designed a titled box with a SVG image (as you see it everywhere, e.g. https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/01-starting-with-data/index.html).

[image]

This

```
<div class="defbox">
  <div class="titeldefbox">
  <svg  class="svgdefbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 382.59 429.36"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ffffff;}</style></defs><g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2"><g id="Ebene_6" data-name="Ebene 6"><g id="definition"><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,128.33c3.88-2.38,7.76-4.4,11.64-6.29,1.94-1,3.88-1.82,5.82-2.74s3.88-1.7,5.82-2.5a5.39,5.39,0,0,1,2.9,0,23.59,23.59,0,0,0,2.91.1l5.81,0,11.61,0,46.48.18,46.47.18,23.23.09,5.8,2.59c1.93.92,3.87,1.78,5.8,2.77,3.86,1.9,7.73,3.91,11.59,6.23-3.88,2.29-7.76,4.27-11.64,6.14-1.94,1-3.88,1.82-5.82,2.72l-5.82,2.55-23.23-.09-46.47-.18L127.6,140,116,140l-5.81,0a21.76,21.76,0,0,0-2.91.07,5.39,5.39,0,0,1-2.9,0c-1.93-.82-3.87-1.69-5.8-2.55s-3.86-1.79-5.8-2.78C88.9,132.8,85,130.75,81.17,128.33Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,192.37c3.88-2.07,7.76-3.82,11.64-5.46,1.94-.85,3.88-1.58,5.82-2.38s3.87-1.48,5.81-2.18a6.36,6.36,0,0,1,2.91.05,25.54,25.54,0,0,0,2.9.09l5.81,0,11.62,0,46.47.18,46.47.18,23.24.09,5.8,2.26c1.93.8,3.86,1.55,5.79,2.4,3.87,1.66,7.74,3.41,11.6,5.43-3.88,2-7.76,3.71-11.64,5.34-1.94.83-3.88,1.57-5.81,2.36L243.78,203l-23.24-.09-46.47-.18-46.47-.18-11.62,0-5.8,0a25.7,25.7,0,0,0-2.91.06,6.18,6.18,0,0,1-2.9,0c-1.94-.71-3.87-1.47-5.8-2.22s-3.87-1.55-5.8-2.42C88.9,196.26,85,194.48,81.17,192.37Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,256.42c1.29-1.07,2.59-1.93,3.88-2.91s2.59-1.76,3.89-2.58,2.58-1.58,3.88-2.38,2.59-1.48,3.88-2.18a2.76,2.76,0,0,1,1.94,0,11.34,11.34,0,0,0,1.93.08l3.87,0,7.75,0,31,.11,31,.12,15.49.06,3.86,2.25c1.29.8,2.58,1.55,3.87,2.4q3.85,2.45,7.72,5.41-3.89,2.94-7.76,5.35c-1.3.85-2.59,1.59-3.89,2.38l-3.88,2.21-15.49-.06-31-.12-31-.11-7.74,0-3.88,0a11.33,11.33,0,0,0-1.93.07,2.87,2.87,0,0,1-1.94,0c-1.29-.71-2.57-1.47-3.86-2.22s-2.58-1.55-3.87-2.41-2.57-1.71-3.86-2.61S82.46,257.49,81.17,256.42Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M320,190.53c2.07-10,4-19.94,5.59-29.95s3.09-20,4.25-30,2-20,2.33-29.83a195.22,195.22,0,0,0-.86-29c-.43-4.64-.62-9.21-1.42-13.5a37.29,37.29,0,0,0-4-11.3,14.79,14.79,0,0,0-6.41-6.31,13.66,13.66,0,0,0-2-.76l-.13,0-.21,0-.41-.12-.83-.21-1.71-.43c-2.31-.56-4.68-1.08-7.09-1.58-9.62-2-19.52-3.61-29.42-5.12s-19.87-2.83-29.85-4.05q-29.92-3.64-60-5.84c-20-1.44-40.11-2.38-60.09-2.49-10-.05-20,.12-29.84.61S78.12,22,68.56,23.39c-4.77.72-9.48,1.6-14,2.72a74.7,74.7,0,0,0-12.67,4.23c-3.8,1.67-7,3.9-8.37,5.77a21.31,21.31,0,0,0-2.4,4.47A57.1,57.1,0,0,0,29,46.68a130.58,130.58,0,0,0-3.09,13.75c-.83,4.75-1.5,9.6-2.08,14.49-1.14,9.78-1.9,19.71-2.46,29.69-1.09,20-1.41,40.07-1.37,60.21.14,40.28,1.7,80.67,4.07,121q1.82,30.24,4.36,60.39c.87,10.05,1.81,20.08,2.89,30.06.55,5,1,10,1.86,14.89.39,2.46.79,4.9,1.11,7.34s.53,4.87.76,7.22a.69.69,0,0,1,0,.2.14.14,0,0,1,0,.07c0,.06,0,.09,0,.14a.9.9,0,0,0,0,.29,2.12,2.12,0,0,0,.4.92,7.2,7.2,0,0,0,1.3,1.32A16.07,16.07,0,0,0,38.8,410a32,32,0,0,0,5.64,2.34A63.21,63.21,0,0,0,51,414.06c9.19,1.89,19.14,2.48,29.08,2.7s20-.22,30.12-.92,20.18-1.73,30.29-3c-9.67,3.2-19.5,5.95-29.44,8.44s-20,4.44-30.28,6a164,164,0,0,1-31.65,1.93,72.89,72.89,0,0,1-8.4-.89,49.33,49.33,0,0,1-8.83-2.24,29.08,29.08,0,0,1-9.39-5.37,22,22,0,0,1-4.25-5,19.48,19.48,0,0,1-1.57-3.17c-.2-.56-.43-1.12-.58-1.69l-.23-.85-.19-.73C15,406.59,14.47,404,14,401.43s-.68-5.15-.94-7.72c-.47-5.14-1.13-10.22-1.67-15.31Q9.8,363.13,8.51,347.91,5.89,317.46,4.11,287C1.71,246.36.14,205.68,0,164.87,0,144.46.28,124,1.4,103.49,2,93.23,2.76,82.94,4,72.58,4.58,67.41,5.3,62.21,6.21,57A151,151,0,0,1,9.8,41.07a78.25,78.25,0,0,1,2.88-8.25A40.13,40.13,0,0,1,17.6,24a33.79,33.79,0,0,1,7.83-7.32,52,52,0,0,1,8.18-4.56A92.93,92.93,0,0,1,49.73,6.71c5.32-1.33,10.59-2.3,15.84-3.1C76.06,2,86.46,1.18,96.82.65s20.67-.69,31-.64c20.57.11,41,1.08,61.43,2.55s40.72,3.46,61,5.93q15.22,1.86,30.42,4.13c10.14,1.54,20.25,3.2,30.49,5.31,2.56.52,5.13,1.09,7.75,1.72l2,.5,1,.26.5.14.58.16a32.88,32.88,0,0,1,14,8.14A37.92,37.92,0,0,1,343.21,37a59.57,59.57,0,0,1,6.28,17.2,78.7,78.7,0,0,1,2.14,16.67c0,2.74-.13,5.45-.34,8.14s-.48,5.34-.8,8c-.63,5.27-1.47,10.47-2.43,15.6-2,10.26-4.45,20.31-7.3,30.21A470.26,470.26,0,0,1,320,190.53Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M238.48,382.75A25.91,25.91,0,0,1,241,380l5.22-5.25,10.44-10.5,41.75-42,41.74-42,20.46-20.59,0,0,22-22-21.91-21.86-21.52,21.59-.09,0-20.87,21-41.75,42-41.74,42L224.27,353l-5.22,5.25a26.93,26.93,0,0,1-2.69,2.54,6.54,6.54,0,0,0-2.65,2.59c-1,2.52-1.87,5.09-2.8,7.65s-1.79,5.18-2.59,7.87a165.74,165.74,0,0,0-4.38,16.51,165.1,165.1,0,0,0,16.48-4.49c2.69-.81,5.23-1.76,7.85-2.63s5.12-1.87,7.64-2.85A6.65,6.65,0,0,0,238.48,382.75Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
  <h2> Definition </h2>
  </div>
  <p>A 
    <strong> definition </strong>
    is a statement of the meaning of a term.
  </p>
</div>
```

should render to that

[image]

But I fail to implement it in my markdown structure. Either I can use pure `css` in the `YAML` header or I can use a entire `.html` file in the `includes` option as is often done for a general everywhere-message like this:

```
output: 
  bookdown::gitbook:
    includes:
      before_body: top_message.html
```

Comment: You didn't include the css style rules for class `svgdefbox` and `titeldefbox`. I am not getting the same HTML output due to lack styles for these classes.

Comment: Hi @shafee I added `svgdefbox` and `titeldefbox`

Comment: I still could not reproduce this, look [here on codepen](https://codepen.io/sshafee/pen/Vwxxevy) what I have got when I ran those html codes along with css.

Comment: Here is the codepen. Sorry, for missing elements. That's because I do not understand all components completely.  https://codepen.io/marco_k/pen/PoeezZj

Comment: I would recommend updating your question (the css part) accordingly to your codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this is using a little bit of javascript to insert that svg element in every places where the classes `.defbox` and `.titeldefbox` are used.

Now for example, if we wanted to use Definition boxes in our **01-intro.Rmd** file, we can use pandoc divs in the following way,

**01-intro.Rmd**

```
# Hello bookdown 

All chapters start with a first-level heading followed by your chapter title, like the line above. There should be only one first-level heading (`#`) per .Rmd file.


:::: {.defbox}

::: {.titeldefbox}

<h2> Definition </h2>

:::

A **definition** is a statement of the meaning of a term.

::::



## More styled box

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tristique nibh mauris, id ullamcorper massa convallis et. Aliquam pharetra rutrum bibendum. Quisque diam lorem, varius ac tincidunt vel, volutpat et est. 


:::: {.defbox}

::: {.titeldefbox}

<h2> More Definition </h2>

:::

Praesent iaculis sed metus sed imperdiet. Nunc vitae augue bibendum, pulvinar neque id, suscipit justo. Quisque convallis, erat vel consectetur mattis, ante est euismod mauris, at condimentum enim erat id lorem. Phasellus volutpat id sapien a sollicitudin. Maecenas nec hendrerit felis.

::::
```

Now notice these divs doesn't contain that tiny little svg icon. We are going to insert those with js in a html file and include that html file with `includes: after_body:` yaml key in the **_output.yml**.

**_output.yml**

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  includes:
    after_body: custom_def.html
```

**custome_def.html**

```
<div class="svg">
  <svg  class="svgdefbox" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 382.59 429.36"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ffffff;}</style></defs><g id="Ebene_2" data-name="Ebene 2"><g id="Ebene_6" data-name="Ebene 6"><g id="definition"><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,128.33c3.88-2.38,7.76-4.4,11.64-6.29,1.94-1,3.88-1.82,5.82-2.74s3.88-1.7,5.82-2.5a5.39,5.39,0,0,1,2.9,0,23.59,23.59,0,0,0,2.91.1l5.81,0,11.61,0,46.48.18,46.47.18,23.23.09,5.8,2.59c1.93.92,3.87,1.78,5.8,2.77,3.86,1.9,7.73,3.91,11.59,6.23-3.88,2.29-7.76,4.27-11.64,6.14-1.94,1-3.88,1.82-5.82,2.72l-5.82,2.55-23.23-.09-46.47-.18L127.6,140,116,140l-5.81,0a21.76,21.76,0,0,0-2.91.07,5.39,5.39,0,0,1-2.9,0c-1.93-.82-3.87-1.69-5.8-2.55s-3.86-1.79-5.8-2.78C88.9,132.8,85,130.75,81.17,128.33Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,192.37c3.88-2.07,7.76-3.82,11.64-5.46,1.94-.85,3.88-1.58,5.82-2.38s3.87-1.48,5.81-2.18a6.36,6.36,0,0,1,2.91.05,25.54,25.54,0,0,0,2.9.09l5.81,0,11.62,0,46.47.18,46.47.18,23.24.09,5.8,2.26c1.93.8,3.86,1.55,5.79,2.4,3.87,1.66,7.74,3.41,11.6,5.43-3.88,2-7.76,3.71-11.64,5.34-1.94.83-3.88,1.57-5.81,2.36L243.78,203l-23.24-.09-46.47-.18-46.47-.18-11.62,0-5.8,0a25.7,25.7,0,0,0-2.91.06,6.18,6.18,0,0,1-2.9,0c-1.94-.71-3.87-1.47-5.8-2.22s-3.87-1.55-5.8-2.42C88.9,196.26,85,194.48,81.17,192.37Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M81.17,256.42c1.29-1.07,2.59-1.93,3.88-2.91s2.59-1.76,3.89-2.58,2.58-1.58,3.88-2.38,2.59-1.48,3.88-2.18a2.76,2.76,0,0,1,1.94,0,11.34,11.34,0,0,0,1.93.08l3.87,0,7.75,0,31,.11,31,.12,15.49.06,3.86,2.25c1.29.8,2.58,1.55,3.87,2.4q3.85,2.45,7.72,5.41-3.89,2.94-7.76,5.35c-1.3.85-2.59,1.59-3.89,2.38l-3.88,2.21-15.49-.06-31-.12-31-.11-7.74,0-3.88,0a11.33,11.33,0,0,0-1.93.07,2.87,2.87,0,0,1-1.94,0c-1.29-.71-2.57-1.47-3.86-2.22s-2.58-1.55-3.87-2.41-2.57-1.71-3.86-2.61S82.46,257.49,81.17,256.42Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M320,190.53c2.07-10,4-19.94,5.59-29.95s3.09-20,4.25-30,2-20,2.33-29.83a195.22,195.22,0,0,0-.86-29c-.43-4.64-.62-9.21-1.42-13.5a37.29,37.29,0,0,0-4-11.3,14.79,14.79,0,0,0-6.41-6.31,13.66,13.66,0,0,0-2-.76l-.13,0-.21,0-.41-.12-.83-.21-1.71-.43c-2.31-.56-4.68-1.08-7.09-1.58-9.62-2-19.52-3.61-29.42-5.12s-19.87-2.83-29.85-4.05q-29.92-3.64-60-5.84c-20-1.44-40.11-2.38-60.09-2.49-10-.05-20,.12-29.84.61S78.12,22,68.56,23.39c-4.77.72-9.48,1.6-14,2.72a74.7,74.7,0,0,0-12.67,4.23c-3.8,1.67-7,3.9-8.37,5.77a21.31,21.31,0,0,0-2.4,4.47A57.1,57.1,0,0,0,29,46.68a130.58,130.58,0,0,0-3.09,13.75c-.83,4.75-1.5,9.6-2.08,14.49-1.14,9.78-1.9,19.71-2.46,29.69-1.09,20-1.41,40.07-1.37,60.21.14,40.28,1.7,80.67,4.07,121q1.82,30.24,4.36,60.39c.87,10.05,1.81,20.08,2.89,30.06.55,5,1,10,1.86,14.89.39,2.46.79,4.9,1.11,7.34s.53,4.87.76,7.22a.69.69,0,0,1,0,.2.14.14,0,0,1,0,.07c0,.06,0,.09,0,.14a.9.9,0,0,0,0,.29,2.12,2.12,0,0,0,.4.92,7.2,7.2,0,0,0,1.3,1.32A16.07,16.07,0,0,0,38.8,410a32,32,0,0,0,5.64,2.34A63.21,63.21,0,0,0,51,414.06c9.19,1.89,19.14,2.48,29.08,2.7s20-.22,30.12-.92,20.18-1.73,30.29-3c-9.67,3.2-19.5,5.95-29.44,8.44s-20,4.44-30.28,6a164,164,0,0,1-31.65,1.93,72.89,72.89,0,0,1-8.4-.89,49.33,49.33,0,0,1-8.83-2.24,29.08,29.08,0,0,1-9.39-5.37,22,22,0,0,1-4.25-5,19.48,19.48,0,0,1-1.57-3.17c-.2-.56-.43-1.12-.58-1.69l-.23-.85-.19-.73C15,406.59,14.47,404,14,401.43s-.68-5.15-.94-7.72c-.47-5.14-1.13-10.22-1.67-15.31Q9.8,363.13,8.51,347.91,5.89,317.46,4.11,287C1.71,246.36.14,205.68,0,164.87,0,144.46.28,124,1.4,103.49,2,93.23,2.76,82.94,4,72.58,4.58,67.41,5.3,62.21,6.21,57A151,151,0,0,1,9.8,41.07a78.25,78.25,0,0,1,2.88-8.25A40.13,40.13,0,0,1,17.6,24a33.79,33.79,0,0,1,7.83-7.32,52,52,0,0,1,8.18-4.56A92.93,92.93,0,0,1,49.73,6.71c5.32-1.33,10.59-2.3,15.84-3.1C76.06,2,86.46,1.18,96.82.65s20.67-.69,31-.64c20.57.11,41,1.08,61.43,2.55s40.72,3.46,61,5.93q15.22,1.86,30.42,4.13c10.14,1.54,20.25,3.2,30.49,5.31,2.56.52,5.13,1.09,7.75,1.72l2,.5,1,.26.5.14.58.16a32.88,32.88,0,0,1,14,8.14A37.92,37.92,0,0,1,343.21,37a59.57,59.57,0,0,1,6.28,17.2,78.7,78.7,0,0,1,2.14,16.67c0,2.74-.13,5.45-.34,8.14s-.48,5.34-.8,8c-.63,5.27-1.47,10.47-2.43,15.6-2,10.26-4.45,20.31-7.3,30.21A470.26,470.26,0,0,1,320,190.53Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M238.48,382.75A25.91,25.91,0,0,1,241,380l5.22-5.25,10.44-10.5,41.75-42,41.74-42,20.46-20.59,0,0,22-22-21.91-21.86-21.52,21.59-.09,0-20.87,21-41.75,42-41.74,42L224.27,353l-5.22,5.25a26.93,26.93,0,0,1-2.69,2.54,6.54,6.54,0,0,0-2.65,2.59c-1,2.52-1.87,5.09-2.8,7.65s-1.79,5.18-2.59,7.87a165.74,165.74,0,0,0-4.38,16.51,165.1,165.1,0,0,0,16.48-4.49c2.69-.81,5.23-1.76,7.85-2.63s5.12-1.87,7.64-2.85A6.65,6.65,0,0,0,238.48,382.75Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
  
</div>


<script>

function add_svg () {
  svg = document.querySelector(".svg svg")
  svg_in = document.querySelectorAll(".defbox .titeldefbox")
  
  for (i = 0; i < svg_in.length; i++) {
    svg_clone = svg.cloneNode(true)
    svg_in[i].insertBefore(svg_clone, svg_in[i].firstElementChild)
  }
}

window.onload = add_svg();

</script>
```

And then add these following css rules in the **style.css**

**style.css**

```
.titeldefbox {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
position: absolute;
background-color: darkslategray;
height: 50px;
color: white;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.defbox {
  background-position: 0px;
background: linear-gradient(
  315deg,
  hsl(240deg 50% 95%) 0%,
  hsl(158deg 13% 64%) 100%
);
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.svgdefbox {
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.defbox h2{
font-size: 16px !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: 20px !important;
padding: 0 0 10px 15px !important;
}

.defbox p{
  margin-top: 40px !important;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0 !important;
}
```

---

[image: styled boxes in bookdown]

---

Comment: Your result looks excellent. But I cannot fully replicate it. I started a fresh bookdown minimal example. The box is fine. But the SVG script is not working. In addition, I plan to have different boxes with different SVG. `add_svg` looks like I need to create one of these functions per icon and box.

Comment: Yes you need to define functions for each svg element. That's why using direct svg tag is a complicated process and is not common to me. I have seen people to use svg image of  icon and for the case of icon you just need to set that icon image as  the background-image for a class and it would work without this mess of using javascript. By the way, Did you use the `custom_def.html` exactly as I have shown. Becasue You can see that, for me its working :)

Comment: Hi shafee, I managed to get it working without SVG. The javascript seems to have some conflicts with another complex script I am running for the `webexercises` package. The code of this is here https://codepen.io/marco_k/pen/RwyBmKY Can you spot why this might not be working with your `add_svg` function?